# How to change audio track order on a .ts video

Tags: linux, h.264

When watching a .ts file, by default, video players like ᴠʟᴄ or Windows media use the first audio channel as the the default audio channel.

In my case, I want to switch the default channel to my language **in any media player without going through audio channel selection**.

So how to change the audio channel order without reenconding the audio and/or video stream on the file itself ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ffmpeg` program to create a new copy of the video file with a different audio track marked as default. ffmpeg is available for Windows, Mac and *NIX. It is a command line program so it will take a little experimentation and work to get it doing what you want. You may also need to use the `ffprobe` command first to get a listing of all the tracks (called streams in ffmpeg) in order to figure out exactly which one you want.

In order to prevent a reduction in quality and save a lot of time by re-encoding the video (not what you want) you can set the codec for the tracks to "copy" and just use the `-map` option to reorder the tracks and/or the `-disposition` option to disable certain tracks by default and enable certain tracks by default.

Comment: So, how I can use the`-map`option for reordering ?

Answer (score -1):

In many video players you can specify your preferred language for an audio and subtitles.

[how to](https://www.howtogeek.com/107902/how-to-make-vlc-pick-the-english-audio-track-automatically/)

Comment: You didn’t read my question correctly. This isn’t about changing the channel each time I play the file on a new computer… But this is about changing metadata in the file so the film is always played in my language straight after I open it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I think this is the way how to make some language track default.:
_Tweaking VLC to Choose a Language
This one is super simple, but not necessarily obvious. Just head into Preferences –> Audio (assuming it’s set to Simple preferences), and then in the “Preferred audio language” box, plug in “EN” without the quotes. As far as we know, you could also use “en”, or “English”, but this is what we tested with. It’s worth noting you could also use this to choose a completely different language as the default—just plug in the two-letter country code._